# Static resource image in formula field

Tags: formula-field, static-resources

How to get/access static resource image in formula field.
static resource name is low and image is low.png.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This example displays the image regardless of the value in any field.

```
IMAGE('/resource/low', "low", 64, 64)
```

This example displays an image of a green square if the amount of an opportunity is greater than 100, a yellow square if it's under 51 and 99, and a red square if it's less or equal to 50. (You have to upload three images for this example)

```
IF( Amount > 100, IMAGE("/resource/Green", "Green"),
IF ( Amount > 50, IMAGE("/resource/Yellow", "Yellow"),
IMAGE("/resource/Red", "Red")))
```

Answer (score 4):

Create formula field with "Text" formula return type, use [IMAGE](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=0&language=en_US) formula

```
IMAGE("/resource/low", "low", 32, 32)
```

> **IMAGE(image_url, alternate_text, height, width)** and replace image_url
>   with the full path to the image. Replace alternate_text with the
>   string of text you want to appear when the image can’t be rendered for
>   some reason. This text can be used by screen reader software. Replace
>   height with the vertical size of the image in pixels. Replace width
>   with the horizontal size of the image in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

**Image('https://~~your_org~~/resource/low/low.png',"",44,44)**

1. https://**your org**/resource/low/low.png - URL to need image in static resource
2. "" - Alternative text - set whatever you need
3. First 44 - height
4. Second 44 - width

Comment: if i'll deploy in another sandbox this will failed because in image you are putting url which definitely change in another sandbox so this will work only in same sandbox that's it.